# Compute the order of an element in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}*$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am asked to find the order of $32+2015\mathbb{Z}$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/2015\mathbb{Z})^\times$

Since the operation is multiplication, this is equivalent to asking for the smallest positive integer $x$ such that $32^x\equiv 1 \mod 2015$

Note that $2015=5*13*31$.

We also know that $x$ has to be a divisor of the order of the group $(\mathbb{Z}/2015\mathbb{Z})^\times$ which is given by $\phi(2015)=\phi(5*13*31)=4*12*30=2^5.3^2.5$ so that $x$ is a factor of $2^5.3^2.5$

I could run through all of the factors $2^x. 3^y.5^z$ where $x$ can be $0,1,2,3$, $y$ can be $0,1,2$ and $z$ can be $0,1$, but this seems like a lot of work. Is there an easier way?

****Update****

I think I recall that the chinese remainder theorem allows us to rewrite this system as

\begin{align*}
32^x &\equiv 1  \mod 5\\
32^x &\equiv 1 \mod 13 \\
32^x &\equiv 1 \mod 31
\end{align*}

but where to go from here?

I see that $x=4$ would work for the first and last congruence, but I don't think it works for the second one.

Comment: The identity of $\mathbb{Z}_{2015}^{\times}$ is the class of $1$, not $0$.

Answer (score 3):

In order that $32^n\equiv 1\pmod{2015}$ we must have
$$32^n\equiv 1\pmod{5},\qquad 32^n\equiv 1\pmod{13},\qquad 32^n\equiv 1\pmod{31}$$
by the CRT. To state $32^n\equiv 1\pmod{5}$ is the same as stating $2^n\equiv 1\pmod{5}$ or $\color{red}{n\equiv 0\pmod{4}}$, since $2$ is a generator for $\mathbb{Z}/(5\mathbb{Z})^*$. In a similar way, since $6$ is a generator for $\mathbb{Z}/(13\mathbb{Z})^*$, due to $6^6\not\equiv 1\pmod{13}$ and $6^4\not\equiv 1\pmod{13}$, to state $32^n\equiv 1\pmod{13}$ is equivalent to stating $\color{orange}{n\equiv 0\pmod{12}}$. At last, $32^n\equiv 1\pmod{31}$ holds for every $n$, so
$$ 32^n\equiv 1\pmod{2015}\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad \color{green}{n\equiv 0\pmod{12}}$$
and the order of $32$ in $\mathbb{Z}/(2015\mathbb{Z})^*$ is $\color{purple}{\large 12}$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you say that $2^n\equiv 1 \mod 5$ is the same as $n\equiv 0 \mod 4$ and how do you know that $6^6$ is not congruent to $1$ mod $13$? Do you just compute these explicitly?

Comment: @user140776: yes, direct computation gives that neither $6^4$ or $6^6$ is $\equiv 1\pmod{13}$, hence $6$ is a generator for $\mathbb{Z}/(13\mathbb{Z})^*$. In a similar way, since $2^2\not\equiv 1\pmod{5}$, $2$ is a generator for $\mathbb{Z}/(5\mathbb{Z})^*$ and $2^n\equiv 1\pmod{5}$ is equivalent to $n\equiv 0\pmod{4}$.

Comment: To ask to compute a discrete logarithm without performing *any* computation is a bit too much :D

Comment: But I thought the point of studying math was to avoid having to do any computations...  ;P

Comment: @user140776: NP-hard problems don't care about your point of view :D

Answer (score 1):

The identity of $(\mathbb{Z}/2015\mathbb{Z})^\times$ is the equivalence class of $1$ because the associated group operation is multiplication. Thus, you should be solving $32^x \equiv 1 \mod 2015$. In fact $32^x \equiv 0 \mod 2015$ has no solutions, this is a consequence of being in the unit group.

Comment: That seems like a lot of work. The problem came with a hint that said to use the chinese remainder theorem.